# pyqt5 problem How to pass data from qlistwidget click item to another .py file?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made a pyqt5 qlistwidget and I want to select an item from qlistwidget and then pass into another B File, but there is an error and I don't know how to fix it

A .py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QListWidget, QWidget, QMessageBox, 
    QApplication, QVBoxLayout)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        listWidget = QListWidget()            
        listWidget.addItem("sparrow") 
        listWidget.addItem("robin")
        listWidget.addItem("crow")            
        listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        vbox.addWidget(listWidget)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('QListWidget')
        self.show()

    def onClicked(self, item):

        print(item.text())
        return item.text()

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

B .py

```
from A import Example

Example().onClicked()
```

Appear Error `TypeError: onClicked() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are directly calling onClicked that won't work.

```
TypeError: onClicked() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'
```

This error is suggesting that you are not passing item to onClicked ( as you are directly calling it like `Example().onClicked()`

**Solution**

You can declare a method `handleClick` on `File B` and call it from `File A` onClicked

**File A**

```
from B import handleClick
class Example ...
  ...
  ...
  onClicked(self,item):
       handleClick(item.text()) #calling the method at File B with item.text()
```

**File B**

```
def handleClick(text):
   print(text)
```

Comment: handleClick(),I get error from B File call `handleClick` function `TypeError: handleClick() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'`

Comment: Don't call it from File b. Read the answer again, You need to import that function in File A and then call it from there (onClicked function at File A).

Comment: it works but I want to get select item from B Flie, what should I do?

Comment: @CHL I'm afraid that you have some confusion about object references and hierarchy, not to mention what classes and instances are and how they work (as it's clear from your question). Why do you need a B file, and why do you need to explicitly get the select item from B and what referenced in the call from A is not enough?

Comment: sorry I'm not very good at class and instances, my goal is to deal with text in B.File

Comment: @CHL that can be achieved as suggested in answer

Comment: successfully executed the result I wanted

Comment: if i want to return text in `def handleClick(text)` to other function to use what sould i do ?

Comment: I think this has became like discussion. And i'm not sure why you want to make this more complicated  but if you want to do so you can call that another function from handleClick like currently we are calling print function. I hope that this will be helpful

Comment: If this is too complicated, do you have any suggestions to improve it?

Comment: @CHL Can't just you use that text in the handleClick function?